# How does vuejs determine component props to update?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js so it seems like I'm just missing something here, but I can't understand why 1 of the 3 different approaches here doesn't update when the values changes. (This code is just me learning Vue.js.) Bonus points for suggesting best practices.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <p>
        <span v-for="(count, state) in stateChanges">{{state}}: {{count}} </span>
    </p>
    <div>
        <state-changes
            :states='["created", "mounted", "updated"]'
            :counters='stateChanges'
        >
        </state-changes>
    </div>
    <div>
        <state-bar
            :counters='stateChanges'
        >
        </state-bar>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
<script>
Vue.component('state-changes', {
    props: ['states', 'counters'],
    template: '\
    <p>\
        <span v-for="state in states">{{state}}: {{counters[state]}} </span>\
    </p>\
    ',
});

Vue.component('state-bar', {
    props: ['counters'],
    template: '\
    <p>\
        <span v-for="(count, state) in counters">{{state}}: {{counters[state]}} </span>\
    </p>\
    ',
})

var vapp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        stateChanges: {
            created: 0,
            mounted: 0,
            updated: 0,
            destroyed: 0
        },
    },
    created: function() {this.stateChanges.created++},
    mounted: function() {this.stateChanges.mounted++},
    updated: function() {this.stateChanges.updated++},
    destroyed: function() {this.stateChanges.destroyed++},
    }
</script>
```

The three approaches I tried are:

1. `<span v-for="(count, state) in stateChanges">{{state}}: {{count}} </span>` outputs:

   created: 1 mounted: 1 updated: 6 destroyed: 0
2. the `<state-changes>` component outputs:

   created: 1 mounted: 1 updated: 6
3. the `<state-bar>` component outputs

   created: 1 mounted: 1 updated: 0 destroyed: 0

I expect all three approaches to work, but the last one doesn't update on changes to the values.

Edit: I thought there was something obvious here, so I excluded a few bits in the code that I shouldn't have, notably the actions that cause the various states to get updated.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmacnaughton/nojvp3dn/1/) with the complete working example. To generate updates click the toggle count (in the original code it was toggling something).

What do I have wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't run (your `data` attribute in `vapp` is not closed properly), and when fixed yields different results than what you've pasted above with Vue edge. https://jsfiddle.net/8tLwntn7/

Comment: Sorry, that's a cut/paste error from a larger file. The data attribute is closed correctly in my code. I'll fix this. (There were other data properties in my original source.)

Comment: Can you create a reproducible jsfiddle with the issue?

Comment: Added jsfiddle showing problem. Click on button to generate updates that illustrates how #3 doesn't show them.

Comment: @deefour - I didn't pick up your comment "different results" until now. My apologies. Thanks for the fiddle; I'll use it, and jsfiddle in general, in the future. I originally thought I was doing something obviously wrong and that the update mechanism didn't matter; this was just a feedback tool as I experimented with Vue.js in other ways.

Comment: I believe this is the result of me breaking the recommendation not to change state in the "updated" method. If I change the source to data that is not updated in the "updated" method then all work.